# Tensorflow TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

while trying to predict the model i am getting this numpy.ndarray error .it  might be the returning statement of the prepare function. what can be possibly done to get rid of this error .
    import cv2
    import tensorflow as tf

```
CATEGORIES = ["Dog", "Cat"]


def prepare(filepath):
    IMG_SIZE = 50  # 50 in txt-based
    img_array = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    return new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)


model = tf.keras.models.load_model("64x3-CNN.model")

prediction = model.predict([prepare('dog.jpg')])
print(prediction)  # will be a list in a list.
```

tried to give the full path still the same error persist.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-f9de27e9ff1e> in <module>
     15 
     16 prediction = model.predict([prepare('dog.jpg')])
---> 17 print(prediction)  # will be a list in a list.
     18 print(CATEGORIES[int(prediction[0][0])])

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the rest of your code looks like. But if you use 'print' as a variable in Python 3 you can get this error:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros((2,2))
print = np.ones((2,2))
print(x)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Comment: what can i possibly do to get the results ? it's a tensorflow model which i called using load_model .i copied this code from a blog and it seems like working for him,but not for me

Answer (score 0):

This type of errors mostly occurs when trying to print an array instead of simple strings or single variable numbers, so I would recommend you to change:

```
17 print(prediction)  # will be a list in a list.
 18 print(CATEGORIES[int(prediction[0][0])])
```

Then you would get:

```
17 print(str(prediction))  # will be a list in a list.
 18 print(str(CATEGORIES[int(prediction[0][0])]))
```